# Embedding of $BV$ and $L^p$ spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

An elementary question about Sobolev spaces:

Is there some explicit theorem about embedding relation between spaces $BV(\Omega)$ and $L^p(\Omega)$?

Formulated otherwise: is $BV$ a subset of $L^2$ (i.e. $BV$ possess regularities of $L^2$) ?

Comment: Besides the good answers: I'd recommend the book "Measure theory and fine properties of functions" by Evans and Gariepy as a reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** The most general imbedding I know of about $L^p$ spaces is that $BV(\Omega) \subset \subset L^{n/n-1}(\Omega)$ where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $n > 1$ (replace $n/(n-1)$ with $1$ when $n=1$). This embedding is **compact** for any $p < n/n-1$. Hence for your $n=2$, $n=3$ interest we have $f \in L^{2}(\Omega)$ for $n=2$ and $f \in L^{3/2}(\Omega)$ for $n=3$. On bounded domains you have all *lower* $L^p$ norms as well by an application of Holder's inequality. Sorry for my initial mis-understanding of your question.

Comment: Thanks Dorian, It gives some sense, seems in the case one-dimension answer is clear, in general also L1 regularity is evident. 

But some doubts of mime (sorry i'm beginner): does concept "imbedding" is different from "embedding"? why you continued argument by  compact imbedding? also what you wanted to imply by your last paragraph about "distributional derivatives", in fact, its connection to my question?

assume my functions are of class BV(r^n) (n=2,3), then in functional analysis i need at least L^2 regularity, then how i should proceed is some assumption/regularization is required?



Comment: Hi there, I fixed my answer to better answer your question. I perhaps am just misspelling imbedding/embedding; they are the same thing. The compactness is not important to you it appears but still interesting in it's own right. You can ignore all statements about compactness above if you don't understand them and just focus on the statements about embeddings.

Answer (score 0):

An $L^1_{loc}$ function  on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is in $BV_{loc}$ iff its distributional derivatives $\partial_i f\in\mathcal{M}^1_{loc}$, i.e. they are all locally finite (Radon) measures. If $n=1$, the situation is well-known, and $BV_{loc}\subset L^\infty_{loc}$. So assume $n\geq 2$. Since $W^{s,p}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^n)\subset C^0_{c}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ if $s>n/p$, you have that $$BV_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n)\subset W^{1-s,p'}_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n)\subset L^{p'}_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n)$$ if $s\leq 1$ and $1/p+1/p'=1$, that is if $p'<n/(n-1)$. On the other hand, when $n>1$,  $1/r^\alpha$ is in $BV_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ if $\alpha<n-1$, since partial derivatives are in $L^1_{loc}$, but it is in $L^q$ only for $q<n/\alpha$, so that $BV_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n)\subset L^q_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ fails for any $q>n/(n-1)$. I wouldn't bet on the limiting case.

Comment: BS: does your answer implies that in general, for n>1, BV(R^n) does not possess regularity of L^p for p>=2?

Comment: It implies that the best local regularity to hope for in $BV(R^n)$ is $L^{n/(n-1)}$. The argument above only gives $L^q$ for any `$q<n/(n-1)$`, but I sort of remember now that this also true for $q=n/(n-1)$ as a consequence of the isoperimetric inequality (the case of characteristic functions in $BV$) and coarea formula  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarea_formula, applied to regularized functions in $BV$. So $BV$ is in $L^2$ for $n\leq2$ (and bounded domains), but not for larger $n$.

Comment: Thanks BS: it gives more sense, what about the connection of H^m to BV spaces, e.g. does every H^m (m>=1) already possess the regularities of BV? 

could you please introduce a minimal text to aid elementary understanding of Sobolev spaces, assuming a little knowledge (not solid) in measure and topology?

Comment: I like Ziemer's "Weakly differentiable functions" for its efficiency, but it might be a bit hard as an introduction. An introduction explicitly aimed at undergraduates is the book "A first course in Sobolev spaces" by Giovanni Leoni, but it is almost 600 pages (twice Ziemer's book). Not minimal, but you can select chapters. You may also want to have a look at Adams' classic "Sobolev spaces" or Tartar's recent book "An introduction to Sobolev spaces and interpolation spaces" for its many historical details and a more PDE oriented POV. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for citing to book, I will try your recipe. But you did not answer my question: does every $H^m(R^n)$ is already a $BV(R^n)$ for $m\geq 1$? also as "Dorian" does not answered me, could you please clarify this issue too: what is the definition of space $(\cdot)_{loc}$ in contrast to $(\cdot)$ (e.g. difference of $L^p$ with $L^p_{loc}$)? does $(\cdot)_{loc}$ possess more regularities or inverse (less regularities)?

Comment: 
$L_{loc}^p$ means that $f \in L^p(K)$ for every **compact** $K$, meaning bounded and closed. In other words, it's integrable on bounded sets. A good example is $f(x) = x^2$ on $\mathbb{R}$. It is in $L_{loc}^p(\mathbb{R})$ for all $p \in [1,\infty]$ but it is not in *any* space $L^p(\mathbb{R})$.

If you are in $H^m(\Omega)$ for any $m \geq 1$ then in fact you can see by Cauchy-Schwartz that you have $ \int |Du(x)| dx \leq C||u||_{H^1}$ but this of course is the $W^{1,1}$ norm and $W^{1,1}$ and $BV$ have the same norm on $W^{1,1}$; $BV$ is just a weaker class.

Comment: Just to be clear, my previous argument shows that if you are in $H^m$ then you are in fact in $W_{loc}^{1,1}$ and consequently in $BV_{loc}$ because $BV \subset W^{1,1}$.

Comment: Dorian, thanks for your help on my misfits. Just a hammer $u$ is in $V_loc$ iff $f.u$ is in $V$ for any smooth compactly supported $f$.
This holds even for distributional spaces $V$, such as negative Sobolev. BTW let me mention that there are (too?) many notations for Sobolev spaces. But by any standards, $H^m$ is $W^{m,2}$ ($m$ derivatives in $L^2$), and you are damn'd right that $W^{1,2}$ is in $W^{1,1}$ on bounded open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ since $L^2\subset L^1$ on such. Just a finishing remark $W^{1,1}$ is to $BV$ like $L^1$ is to $\mathcal{M}^1$ (finite measures). Hope this helps. 